# How to get the time spent inside and outside in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a simple table which stores employees clock-ins and clock-outs throughout the day:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╗
║ Employee ║  PunchDateTime   ║ ActionType ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 08:00 ║ IN         ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 08:12 ║ IN         ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 08:50 ║ OUT        ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 09:29 ║ IN         ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 10:35 ║ OUT        ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 10:55 ║ OUT        ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 11:42 ║ IN         ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 12:38 ║ IN         ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 16:21 ║ OUT        ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 16:49 ║ OUT        ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

I want build a query that calculates time spent in and out. The end result should look like this:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║ Employee ║  PunchDateTime   ║ ActionType ║ TimeIn ║ TimeOut ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 08:00 ║ IN         ║ -      ║ -       ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 08:12 ║ IN         ║ -      ║ -       ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 08:50 ║ OUT        ║ 00:40  ║ -       ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 09:29 ║ IN         ║ -      ║ 00:39   ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 10:35 ║ OUT        ║ 02:23  ║ -       ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 10:55 ║ OUT        ║ 01:26  ║ -       ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 11:42 ║ IN         ║ -      ║ 01:07   ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 12:05 ║ IN         ║ -      ║ 01:10   ║
║ John     ║ 2014/03/26 16:21 ║ OUT        ║ 04:16  ║ -       ║
║ Mark     ║ 2014/03/26 16:49 ║ OUT        ║ 05:07  ║ -       ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

Criteria:

- The results need to be by user, per one day. If the interval is longer than one day, the total time spent must be calculated for each day
- Double ins/outs will be disregarded, outermost should be used (so in,in,out means track time from the first in to the out)
- I need only daily results. If the employee enters at the end of the day, and exits the next day, it will be ignored. Starting from the first valid IN and last valid OUT.
- The time spent will be calculated only for valid pairs of INs and OUTs, eliminating those that can't be paired (two or more consecutive INs/OUTs)

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4313d/3)

Graphical representation of how to calculate TimeIn and TimeOut (for one employee):
[image]

Comment: Do you need the results by day? or by user? It's not clear from your expected result shown.

Comment: I think it is easier to achieve getting data from sql server and then parse with your code

Comment: What if someone clocks in twice without clocking out inbetween?

Comment: From experience, this is a very complex type of system to model because you usually start thinking about "What if he clocks in at 7:15 when he normally starts 8:00. Is he comped 45 minutes he can then leave early without being deducted time? What if he clocks in at 6:45? What if he clocks in at 12:00 for the first time that day, is that legal or should he deducted 1 hour until 9, and have to file for vacation/time off for the remainder? What about clocking in/out during lunchbreak?"

Comment: The time spent will be calculated only for valid pairs of INs and OUTs, eliminating those that can't be paired (two or more consecutive INs/OUTs).

Comment: I'm asking about duplicate ins and outs because this will make it more difficult doing this in a query. For instance, in a in-in-out scenario, you probably want to match the first in with the out, but then you absolutely don't want to match the second in with anything, otherwise you will track that time twice.

Comment: The results need to be by user, per one day. If the interval is longer than one day, the total time spent must be calculated for each day.

Comment: So if he clocks in at 22:45 and then out at 02:45, you need to split that amount on two days?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the new criteria into the question. As I said, this is a complex query, I'm not sure that SQL is the best way to do this.

Comment: That's a different case. First, I need only daily results. If the employee enters at the end of the day, and exits the next day, it will be ignored. Starting from the first valid IN and last valid OUT.

Comment: So can you edit in an example of how the numbers should look if you clock in the next day for John?

Comment: could you provide a sql fiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4313d/3

Comment: Lasse, if the last record of the day is an IN, you ignore it. The same if the first record is an OUT.

Comment: I understand that but this is getting exceedingly hard to specify using a SQL query, that's my point. This is *not* an easy query to write because SQL is extremely good to specify how to filter rows by looking at each row individually, but here you need to filter out some rows looking for the presence of other rows nearby, and not all those rows, only those on the same date.

Comment: What version of SQL? SQL 2012 has a load of new functions which make this much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Punch') is not null
    drop table #Punch

create table #Punch(
    Employee varchar(50) not null,
    PunchDateTime datetime not null,
    ActionType varchar(3) not null
)

insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 06:00', 'OUT' -- extra "out"
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:00', 'IN'
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:01', 'IN' -- extra "in"
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:02', 'IN' -- extra "in"
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:03', 'IN' -- extra "in"
insert into #Punch select 'Mark', '2014/03/26 08:12', 'IN'
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:50', 'OUT'
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:51', 'OUT' -- extra "out"
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:52', 'OUT' -- extra "out"
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 08:53', 'OUT' -- extra "out"
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 09:29', 'IN'
insert into #Punch select 'Mark', '2014/03/26 10:35', 'OUT'
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 10:55', 'OUT'
insert into #Punch select 'Mark', '2014/03/26 11:42', 'IN'
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 12:38', 'IN'
insert into #Punch select 'John', '2014/03/26 16:21', 'OUT'
insert into #Punch select 'Mark', '2014/03/26 16:49', 'OUT'

select *
from (
    select
        p.Employee,
        p.PunchDateTime,
        p.ActionType,
        case when p.ActionType = 'IN' 
            then '-' 
            else coalesce(substring(convert(varchar(30), p.PunchDateTime - p.PreviousPunchDateTime, 20), 12, 5), '-')
        end as TimeIn,
        case when p.ActionType = 'OUT' 
            then '-' 
            else coalesce(substring(convert(varchar(30), p.PunchDateTime - p.PreviousPunchDateTime, 20), 12, 5), '-')
        end as TimeOut
    from (
        select
            a.Employee,
            a.PunchDateTime,
            a.ActionType,
            (
                select top 1 b.PunchDateTime 
                from #Punch b 
                where b.Employee = a.Employee 
                    and b.PunchDateTime < a.PunchDateTime
                    and b.ActionType <> a.ActionType
                    and datediff(day, b.PunchDateTime, a.PunchDateTime) = 0 -- same day
                    and not exists(
                        select 1
                        from #Punch c
                        where c.Employee = a.Employee
                            and c.ActionType = a.ActionType
                            and c.PunchDateTime < a.PunchDateTime
                            and c.PunchDateTime > b.PunchDateTime
                    )
                    and not (
                        b.ActionType = 'OUT'
                        and not exists(select 1 from #Punch d where d.Employee = a.Employee and d.ActionType = 'IN' and d.PunchDateTime < b.PunchDateTime)
                    )
                order by b.PunchDateTime asc
            ) as PreviousPunchDateTime
        from #Punch a
    ) p
) p2
where not (p2.ActionType = 'OUT' and p2.TimeIn = '-' and p2.TimeOut = '-')
    and not (
        p2.ActionType = 'IN' and p2.TimeIn = '-' and p2.TimeOut = '-'
        and exists(select 1 from #Punch a where a.ActionType = 'IN' and a.Employee = p2.Employee and a.PunchDateTime < p2.PunchDateTime))
order by
    p2.PunchDateTime
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem with the second criteria: Double ins/outs will be disregarded, outermost should be used (so in,in,out means track time from the first in to the out)

Comment: @milo2011- I revised my answer to account for the additional criteria

Comment: It accounts correct for the double INs, but not for the double OUTs. Should calculate for the last OUT found after an IN.

Comment: Are you sure?  It makes sense to me that we consider the first punch "in" as when the worker is "in".  Seems like we'd want to consider the first punch "out" as when the worker is "out".

Comment: Please see the photo I've added in the problem description above.

Comment: @milo2011- I updated the query to discard records from the output based on the logic in your photo.  Let me know if the output looks correct.

Comment: It calculates correctly the TimeIn, but not the TimeOut (it doesn't discard the IN at 10:24, instead it wrongly discards the one at 16:48).

Comment: I think I have it right- from your criteria:  _outermost should be used (so in,in,out means track time from the **first in** to the out)_.  10:24 is the **first in**.  16:48 should be discarded.

Comment: OUT, IN, IN - means to track time from the first OUT to the last IN.

Comment: I'm talking about the calculation of the TimeOut: employee goes out at 10:22, then IN at 10:24, and again IN as 16:48, so the difference TimeOut should be 16:48 - 10:22.